# Genymotion doesn't work "ADB server didn't ACK" on Windows

Tags: android, windows, emulation, genymotion

I can't run Genymotion on my PC. I've already changed the path of the ADB location to my local ADB.
[image]

In Android Studio all SDK packages are up to date and I've got the path to the local SDK from Android Studio so it is using the same.

If I am trying to show all devices I get the error:
[image]

My environment:

- Windows 10
- Genymotion Version 2.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when the `adb` binary used by Genymotion is incompatible with the one from Android Studio.

The setting you set should avoid the problem, but you must "reset" your setup to make sure all the softs use the exact same adb binary. I suggest you to close all the Genymotion devices, then close Android Studio and restart all.

Also, check that the `adb` you are using on your terminal is the one from the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you! My powershell was using another ADB on my computer and not the one from Android Studio. Now it is working